# Problems with crontab du to curl

Tags: debian, disk-usage, curl

I am trying to send the output of a `treesize` command to my webserver for further processing.

Problems with the line that's set in my crontab below:

- When running the command manually, it works fine, but newlines from the du command are replaced for whitespaces. How to keep the newlines in it? PHP is storing the posted data to a text file on my server.
- When I schedule it with crontab, do data is submitted to the given URL. How to make the output of the DU command get posted to curl in a crontab?

How to fix this?

`du -ha --max-depth=1 /mnt/datafolders | curl --data-binary @-http://10.0.0.11:81/sendstats.php`

Comment: it is hard to tell the nature of your problem but it sounds like there is `CR`/`LF` conversion issue here. check and see if you have `unix2dos` application installed. if not install it using apt-get or yum , depending on your linux variety. then insert `unix2dos` command just before `curl` in the pipe.. like this `...afolders | unix2dos | curl --da...` and see if it helps. If not, post samples of what you're getting on the output

Comment: you have to use full command paths in cron. To get to know your path type `which du` and `which curl` then edit your cron schedule accordingly

Comment: When I use the crontab with the full paths, so logfile is created by fileserver, but crontab sends me a mail containing:
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0 100  2268    0     0  100  2268      0   479k --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  738k

Answer (score 0):

Adding --silent fixed it. I will handle the newlines begin ignored in PHP.